# Is there a way to make a variable created within an isset($_GET[]) condition be accessed inside an isset($_POST[]) condition?

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I have been stuck on this following problem for the past few days which I cannot seem to resolve.

I have the following two **if statements** within a PHP file:

**This statement gets the post ID from the previous page.**

```
if(isset($_GET['post'])){

    $post_id = $_GET['post'];
}
```

**This statement inserts user inputs into a DB_Table after a button is clicked. Amongst the data inserted into the DB_Table, I want the $post_id from the (isset($_GET['post'])) condition to be one of them.**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $insert_member = "insert into hcg_members (post_id, member_id) values ('$post_id','$match_member_id')";

    $run_event = mysqli_query($con,$insert_member);
 }
```

Only problem is, I can't seem to find a way to retain the $post_id's data. I have tried to set $post_id as a $Globals variable but this does not work.

As a way to find troubleshoot the problem I have successfully echoed $post_id from outside the if(isset($_GET[])) statement but the echo statement stops working once I try to run it from the if(isset($_POST[])) statement.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: I think we need to see more code. Looks like you are trying to do 2 separate requests, a GET and a POST. Variables set in one request will not be available to subsequent requests

Comment: i have a sneaking suspicion you are doing two different actions on your page that are making two separate calls to your script (one a GET request and one a POST request).  http is a stateless protocol, which means php doesn't remember anything from the previous request unless you specifically carry it over.  e.g. look into putting `$post_id` into a session variable, or use some js to pop a hidden field on button click so that it's included in the POST request, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, apologies if my question is unclear.  Crayon Violent is spot on. I am trying to make 2 different calls to my script, one a GET request and the other a POST request while retaining the $post_id variable from the GET request to the POST request. I will try to use a session variable in order not to lose the $post_id data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so just to clarify for those who found my question unclear. I was trying to make 2 different calls to my script.

- The first one was a GET request.
- The second one was a POST request.

I was trying to do the above while retaining the value of $post_id  which was located in the GET request when using it in the POST request.

As advised by **dan08** & **Crayon Violent**, variables' values cannot be retained when trying to pass them from one HTTP request method to another. As pointed out by **Crayon Violent**, http is a stateless protocol, which makes PHP unable to remember anything from the previous request.

I therefore used one of **Crayon Violent**'s solution which was to use session in order to carry over the variable from the Get Request method to the POST Request method, and it worked! :)

**There's the solution:**

GET Request Method:

```
<?php 
    @session_start(); 
    if(isset($_GET['post'])){
        $post_id = $_GET['post'];
         $_SESSION['respite_id'] = $post_id;
    }   
         ...
         ...
?>
```

POST Request Method:

```
<?php 
    include("includes/database.php");

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

     $respite_id = $_SESSION['respite_id'];

     $insert_member = "insert into hcg_members (post_id, member_id) values ('$post_id','$match_member_id')";
     $run_event = mysqli_query($con,$insert_member);            
        ...
        ...

    }
?>
```

**Thanks again to dan08 and Crayon Violent's support! :)**

Answer (score 0):

This code produces the below query when for example $_GET['post'] = 5, which looks fine to me. Could you elaborate on what goes wrong? Does this code somehow resides in different functions, so it could be a case of variables not being accessible?

insert into hcg_members (post_id, member_id) values ('5','')